# Converting an initial in one array to match a full name in another works, but not when arrays are different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below function created the array modified by comparing array1 to array2 to find either 1) an intitial in array1 that corresponds to a name in array 2 and converts that initial or 2) finds a name in array1 that corresponds to an initial in array2 and converts that name to match the initial.

```
var array1 = ['fred', 's'];
var array2 = ['sue', 'fred'];

var modified = [];

//create a new modified array that converts initials to names and vice versa
array1.forEach(function(element) {
    modified.push(array2.find((el) => el.startsWith(element[0])));
    var index = array2.indexOf(array2.find((el) => el.startsWith(element[0])));
    if (index > -1) {
        array2.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
console.log(modified); //['fred', 'sue']
```

Which is what is expected. Even if there are no initials, the new array will simply match array 1, which is expected.

```
var array1 = ['fred', 'sue'];
var array2 = ['sue', 'fred'];
console.log(modified); //['fred', 'sue']
```

if array1 is shorter than array2, it works as expected:

```
var array1 = ['fred'];
var array2 = ['sue', 'fred'];
console.log(modified); // ['fred']
```

However, i'm not getting expected results when array 1 is longer than array2:

```
var array1 = ['fred', 'sue'];
var array2 = ['sue'];
console.log(modified); // ['undefined', 'sue'] // should be ['fred', 'sue']
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `.find()` returns `undefined` if it doesn't find a match. You're pushing that onto `modified`.

Comment: so then what's my alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the result of `.find()` onto `modified` even if it doesn't find anything. You should default to the string you're searching for.

And instead of calling `.find()` twice, use `findIndex()` to get the index once, and use that when pushing and when splicing.

```js
var array1 = ['fred', 'sue'];
var array2 = ['sue'];
modified = [];

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  var index = array2.findIndex(el => el.startsWith(element[0]));
  if (index > -1) {
    modified.push(array2[index]);
    array2.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    modified.push(element);
  }
});

console.log(modified);
```

Comment: Just found a problem with the above: If array 2 = ['frederick', 'susan'], modified will = ['frederick, 'susan']'. This should not happen. Fred is not an initial of Frederick and 'sue' isn't an intiial of 'susan'.